# mysql string group_concat giving me an error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

i'm getting an error here when i try this sql ...

```
SELECT customers.customers_first_name GROUP_CONCAT(customers_groups.customers_hash SEPARATOR '') 
FROM customers INNER JOIN customers_groups ON (customers.hash = customers_groups.customers_hash) 
GROUP BY customers.customers_entry_date



CUSTOMERS DATABASE
`customers_id`, 
`customers_first_name`, 
`customers_surname`, 
`customers_telephone`, 
`customers_email`, 
`customers_telephone_active`, 
`customers_email_active`, 
`client_type`, 
`customers_hash`, 
`customers_entry_date`

CUSTOMERS_GROUPS
`groups_hash`
`customers_hash
```

Comment: `SELECT customers.customers_first_name GROUP_CONCAT(customers_groups.customers_hash SEPARATOR '')`is missing a comma to separate the columns.. Should be `SELECT customers.customers_first_name,  GROUP_CONCAT(customers_groups.customers_hash SEPARATOR '')`... i vote close this question because it looks like to be a simple typographical error.

Comment: Please, post the error message when asking this kind of question

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should post the error message with the question but check below solution.

```
SELECT customers.customers_first_name, GROUP_CONCAT(customers_groups.customers_hash SEPARATOR '') 
FROM customers INNER JOIN customers_groups ON (customers.hash = customers_groups.customers_hash) 
GROUP BY customers.customers_entry_date
```

SELECT customers.customers_first_name **,**

> "," was missing in the select statement before GROUP_CONCAT